# Achieving certain rendering styles

Tags: rendering, graphics-programming

I'm trying to assess the difficulty of creating a rendering style that is more like the game Okami and the Quake mods (as shown on [this page](http://modetwo.net/users/nachimir/vga/)...search for 'okami','quake npr').  Here's a [better page describing the Quake rendering mod](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~kwysoc/npr/stat1/).

Can a game engine such as Unity be used and programmed to achieve these kind of rendering styles?

I'm doing research and am totally new to this so any insight into this would help tremendously.

Answer (score 6):

Through the use of [Shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader) Unity can have a variety of rendering styles.

The [Unify Community Wiki](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Shaders) has a variety of articles dealing with the subject of shaders, complete with source code.

Creating Post-Processing shaders such as the ones in your example requires a Unity Pro license.

Comment: No, it does not. Creating post-processing effects requires Pro, but new shaders can be created and used in Indie too.

Comment: @Nevermind I didn't know it was post-processing effect shaders only, will fix. To note, the shaders in the OP's example link were mostly post-processing style specifically the example of Okami and Quake NPR.

Comment: Toon-shading (cel-shading) doesn't have to be post-process and will allow results that are already close to what the OP wants.

Comment: @Bumm I could see the NPR example being pulled off without post processing, but I can't see how the Bloom/Watercolor style of Okami could be pulled off with just material shaders.

Comment: I'm a total beginner in Unity and also in shading. After looking at the shading syntax, I'm not sure I understand how we can get the sketch look and feel. The sketchiness of the lines need to be in the model or texture right?